# Proof by reduction definition in "Serious Cryptography": Cipher reduced to hardness problem or other way around?

Tags: provable-security, hardness-assumptions

In Serious Cryptography by Jean-Philippe Aumasson on p. 46, paragraph "Provable Security", it says:

> Provable security is about proving that breaking your crypto scheme is at least as hard as solving another problem known to be hard. [...] This type of proof is called a reduction [...]. **We say that breaking some cipher is reducible to problem $X$ if any method to solve problem $X$ also yields a method to break the cipher**.

I am wondering if this is the right direction. Assume we reduce the problem of breaking a cipher $P$ to some problem $X$, $P \leq_m^p X $, as suggested by the book (if I understand correctly). Then if we have a polynomial-time algorithm for $X$, we also have a polynomial algorithm for $P$. But this does not guarantee that if no polynomial algorithm for $X$ exists, there should be no polynomial-time algorithm for breaking $P$. In fact, there could still be a polynomial-time algorithm breaking $P$ in some way unrelated to problem $X$.

So shouldn't the reduction be the other way around $X \leq_m^p P$. That is, if we can break $P$ in polynomial time, we can also solve $X$ in polynomial time? This way, if $X$ is hard (not polynomial-time solvable), then by contraposition $P$ must also be hard, thus $P$ is **at least as hard as** X?

What am I missing here?

Comment: In brief, your understanding of all this is correct; you aren’t missing anything. To show that “breaking your crypto scheme P is at least as hard as solving some other problem X,” you would need to give a reduction from X to P, i.e., show $X \leq P$. In words, show that any algorithm for solving P can be used (efficiently) to solve X.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions come from [Turing Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) of Wikipedia

> In computability theory, a Turing reduction (also known as a Cook reduction) from a problem A to a problem B, is a reduction which solves A, assuming the solution to B is already known (Rogers 1967, Soare 1987). It can be understood as an algorithm that could be used to solve A if it had available to it a subroutine for solving B. More formally, a Turing reduction is a function computable by an oracle machine with an oracle for B. Turing reductions can be applied to both decision problems and function problems.

which can be simplified as $A$ is reduced to $B$;

- If $A \leq B$ then, if you were given a subroutine for $B$ you could solve $A$.
- This can be also mean that $A$ is no harder than $B$.

> I am wondering if this is the right direction. Assume we reduce the problem of breaking a cipher $P$ to some problem $X$, $P \leq_m^p X $, as suggested by the book (if I understand correctly). Then if we have a polynomial-time algorithm for $X$, we also have a polynomial algorithm for $P$. But this does not guarantee that if no polynomial algorithm for $X$ exists, there should be no polynomial-time algorithm for breaking $P$. In fact, there could still be a polynomial-time algorithm breaking $P$ in some way unrelated to problem $X$.

So we have $P \leq X$, which means we use $X$ as a subroutine and $P$ is not harder than $X$.

Yes, the reduction doesn't say about a polynomial-time algorithm exists or not. If one can prove that there is no polynomial-time algorithm for $X$ than this doesn't mean that there is no for $P$. Because the reduction is just a useful upper bound.

If there is a polynomial-time algorithm for $P$ this can be used to solve $X$ if one can show that $X \leq P$. Otherwise, as stated in the second bullet, the reduction provides only the upper bound.

> So shouldn't the reduction be the other way around $X \leq_m^p P$. That is, if we can break $P$ in polynomial time, we can also solve $X$ in polynomial time?

Not exactly, the reduction gives the upper bound. To use a polynomial-time algorithm for $P$ to solve $X$ one needs to show that $X \leq P$.

> This way, if $X$ is hard (not polynomial-time solvable), then by contraposition $P$ must also be hard, thus $P$ is **at least as hard as** X?
>   What am I missing here?

Assuming that one showed a reduction of $X \leq P$, then the information we have $X$ is no harder than $P$ with $P$ is solvable in polynomial-time. If you show that $X$ is hard ( assuming NP-hard here) then one must look at either the reduction or the hardness of solving $P$ again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the upper bound? So after showing $P \leq X$, we have shown an upper bound for what? About $X \leq P$: I thought that if we show $X \leq P$ and $X$ is say, NP-hard, then $P$ is also NP-hard (by contraposition). Therefore, if we want to show that $P$ is at least as hard as $X$, we need to show $X \leq P$?

Comment: With the reduction $P \leq X$, $X$ stands for an upper bound for $P$. $P$ cannot be harder than $X$. One can always use $X$ to solve $P$. If you one show that $X \leq P$ then $P$ is upper bound for $X$, i.e. $X$ cannot be harder than $P$. If you consider the $P$ as polynomial time than there is problem with the reducetion or the NP-hardness or the polynomial-timeness of P.

Comment: So if we assume $X$ is a hard problem (discrete logarithm for example) and we create a new cipher on that and let $P$ be the problem of breaking that cipher. Than to show "breaking your crypto scheme (=P) is at least as hard as solving another problem known to be hard (=X)" we need to reduce $X \leq P$, right?

Comment: If you provide a reduction for $X \leq P$ then you showed that if you can break $P$ then you can break $X$. If you also show that $P \leq X$ we can consider them like equal complexity classes.